# Ruby on Rails - Undefined methods for NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, updates, rating

I'm creating a picture-rating app where users can click on pictures and rate them on a scale from 1 to 5. I'm trying to calculate the average rating of a picture. Before when users clicked on a rating value, that value became the picture's rating.

```
Rating: 5
```

If a user clicked on 1, the rating would change to 1

```
Rating: 1
```

When reality, the rating should have been 3.

```
(5 + 1) / 2
=> 3
```

Here's what I've accomplished so far in implementing this feature.

I added a migration to create two new columns for my Pictures Table

```
rails g migration AddRatingsToPictures ratings_count: integer, rating_total: integer
```

Both the new attributes, ratings_count and rating_total are integer types, meaning they are assigned a nil value at default.

```
p = Picture.first
p.attribute_names
=> ['id', 'title', 'category', 'stars', 'updated_at', 'created_at', 
'ratings_count', 'rating_total']
p.ratings_count
=> nil
p.rating_total
=> nil
```

My only problem is the NilClass Error.

Here is my update method in my PicturesController.

```
def update
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  @picture.ratings_count = 0 if @picture.stars.nil?
  @picture.rating_total = @picture.stars
  @picture.rating_total += @picture.stars if @picture.stars_changed?
  @picture.ratings_count += 1 if @picture.rating_total_changed?
  if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
    unless current_user.pictures.include?(@picture)
      @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
      current_user.pictures << @picture
      redirect_to @picture, :flash => { :success => "Thank you! This picture has been added to your Favorites List" }
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      flash[:success] = 'Thank you! This picture has been updated' 
    end
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Here is my picture_param method in my PicturesController

```
 def picture_params
  params.require(:picture).permit(:title, :category, :genre, :stars)
end
```

Here is what the two new columns do

```
ratings_count: Calculates the number of times a picture has been rated
rating_total: Calculates the sum of the stars a picture has received
```

In the above code, I first set the ratings_count to 0 if the picture doesn't have a rating. This means that the picture hasn't been rated yet.

I then need to initially set the rating_total to the number of stars a picture has. If a user changed the star rating, I would add those stars to the rating_total. And if the total increased, that's my cue to increase the number of ratings.

Obviously, to calculate the average, I'd do something like this.

```
(@picture.rating_total / @picture.ratings_count).to_f
```

Now, I think I have the right idea but I know why this doesn't work. When columns are created with an integer value, by default they are set to nil. This leads to a NilClass Error when I load the web page.

```
undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my code in the View

```
<li><strong>Rating:</strong> <%= pluralize((@picture.rating_total / @picture.ratings_count), 'Star') %></li>
```

Comment: If you want to calculate an average, you're either going to have to:   

1) Save an array of ratings, and do the math - ie, `(@picture.star_ratings.inject(0) { |total, v| total = total + v } / @picture.star_ratings.count)` (or you could use SQL to calculate it too)     
2) Save a 'total rating count' and a 'total number of ratings count' separately in the database.. `@picture.rating_total / @picture.rating_count`

Comment: @JustinAiken That should probably be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the main reason it is not working is because

- you fetch the picture
- you check the `stars` from the database, and the NOT the passed form-parameters
- you do update_attributes, which if I am not mistaken, used to set attributes and then save the complete object, but since rails 4 only updates the passed attributes (which is what you would expect)

One small remark: keeping the rating correct is a function I would place in the model, NOT in the controller.

Furthermore, how to handle the *if nil, initialise to zero* I wrote a short [blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=664) about. In short: overrule the getter.

So I would propose the following solution. In your model write

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base


  def ratings_count
    self[:ratings_count] || 0
  end

  def ratings_total
    self[:ratings_total] || 0
  end


  def add_rating(rating)
    return if rating.nil? || rating == 0

    self.ratings_count += 1
    self.ratings_total += rating
    self.stars = self.ratings_total.to_f / self.ratings_count
    self.save
  end

  def rating
    return 0 if self.ratings_count == 0
    self.ratings_total.to_f / self.ratings_count
  end
```

and then the code in your controller becomes much cleaner and readable:

```
def update
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

  stars = picture_params.delete(:stars)

  if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
    @picture.add_rating stars
    unless current_user.pictures.include?(@picture)
      current_user.pictures << @picture
      redirect_to @picture, :flash => { :success => "Thank you! This picture has been added to your Favorites List" }
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      flash[:success] = 'Thank you! This picture has been updated' 
    end
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

I first delete the `:stars` from the parameters, because I do not want to save those, I want to use those for the `add_rating`. I then try to `update_attributes`, which will fail if there are any failing validations, and if that is ok, I will `add_rating` which itself will handle nil or zero correctly. Well granted: I do not know how you handle a "non-rating" (nil? zero?). It is possible a rating of zero should be added, because it will add a rating, but most UI I know do not allow to select 0 as rating, so you might want to change the zero handling.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. This was an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the case of uninitialized (nil) values in your attributes...

```
def update
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  if @picture.stars_changed?
    @picture.ratings_count = (@picture.ratings_count || 0) + 1
    @picture.rating_total = (@picture.rating_total || 0) + ( @picture.stars || 0)
  end
```

You don't need an array of ratings or ratings persisted to database, assuming you only count votes where the rating changes, you can accumulate the count and the total and divide the two (which is, in fact, what you're doing so I'm preaching to the converted).

Although it seems to me that if I change a picture from 5 to 1 and it only changes to 3, I'm gonna keep clicking 1 :)

Comment: Mind you, if you don't want to count the same user twice (him clicking replaces his previous vote) then you will need to persist the votes to a table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like I still receive the same NilClass Error. Maybe I need to nest this code inside the if update_attributes block?

Comment: No, because you need to update the fields before you write them.  What line (exactly) are you getting the error?

Comment: I got that line on 10 of my Pictures#Show method. The last line of code in my post. The error comes from the view it looks like. I tried testing it out on the console, and changing the stars value for the variable p, representing a Picture option. When I checked both p.ratings_count and p.rating_total it still returned nil.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default value on the migration when you created it. But no worries, you can create a new migration to change it:

```
# Console
rails g migration change_default_for_ratings_count_and_rating_total

# Migration Code
class ChangeDefaultForRatingsCountAndRatingTotal < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_column :pictures, :ratings_count, :integer, default: 0
    change_column :pictures, :rating_total,  :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that some databases don't automatically assign newly updated default values to existing column entries, so maybe you will have to iterate over every picture already created with nil values and set to 0.

Comment: Perfect, I never knew about the default option. But your code gives me one question. in migration files, isn't the name of the migration supposed to be CamelCase? I'm reading RubyonRails guides and that seems to be the convention they use. Though maybe it's different if your changing an existing migration?

Comment: When generating the migration, both actions will lead to the same outcome. Keep up with the guide by the way, it is very good :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, an alternative...

Do an `after_initialize` so the fields are never, never, ever nil. Even if you're creating a new Picture object, they'll be initialized as zero. Problem will go away.

```
  class Picture << ActiveRecord::Base

    after_initialize do |picture|
      picture.ratings_count ||= 0
      picture.rating_total ||= 0
    end

    ...
  end
```